# How can I use all objects in a table as a label - input in a model in Django's Admin?

Tags: python, django, admin, models

I want to know if there's some easy way to have 2 models, for example Language, and Word. And we have another model Translation that has the string of the translation and both Models are referenced with a Foreign Key.

Imagine I have 2 languages, English and Spanish. Is there some way to make always appear every language as a label and the string of the translation as a textbox?

Comment: not sure what you want, but Django has extensive support for i18n and l10n, search the docs for Internationalization and Localization.

Comment: No, i'm not searching for i18n, it's just an example. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Could you please make it clearer?

Comment: I would like to have in the Translation form of the Admin interface a label with every language I have inserted and a textbox for it's value. Is it clear enough? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your issue, I think you should look at [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

For instance, let's say you have the following models.

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Word(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField()
    translations = models.ManyToMany(Language, through='Translation')

class Translation(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    value = models.CharField()
```

Then you could have this in your `admin.py`:

```
class TranslationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Translation
    readonly_fields = ['language']

    def get_max_num(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Language.objects.all().count()

    def get_min_num(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_max_num(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial(self, request):
        return [
            {'language': l}
            for l in Language.objects.exclude(pk__in=self.get_queryset(request))
        ]

@admin.register(Word)
class WordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TranslationInline]

    def _create_formsets(self, request, obj, change):
        formsets = []
        inline_instances = []
        prefixes = {}
        get_formsets_args = [request]
        if change:
            get_formsets_args.append(obj)
        for FormSet, inline in self.get_formsets_with_inlines(*get_formsets_args):
            prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
            prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
            if prefixes[prefix] != 1 or not prefix:
                prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])
            formset_params = {
                'instance': obj,
                'prefix': prefix,
                'queryset': inline.get_queryset(request),
            }
            if hasattr(inline, 'get_initial'):
                formset_params['initial'] = inline.get_initial(request)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                formset_params.update({
                    'data': request.POST,
                    'files': request.FILES,
                    'save_as_new': '_saveasnew' in request.POST
                })
            formsets.append(FormSet(**formset_params))
            inline_instances.append(inline)
        return formsets, inline_instances
```

This will enable you to add/edit translations of a word in the admin.

Comment: Thank you, I knew about this before. This provides you a select with every "Language". I want the same but i don't want to select every Language. I want to add a translation for all the languages that have been already inserted into the database. That's what I mean when I wrote label - textbox.

I mean, If I have Spanish and English it should show a label with the word "Spanish" and a textbox and the same with English.

Seriously, I'm sorry for my bad explanation, thank you very much.

Comment: You can set 'language' as `readonly_field` and provide intial data by overriding `get_formset()`. Let me edit my post.

Comment: I edited my answer. Something like this should work. Obviously it is just an example to show the idea, I didn't test it.

Comment: I understand what you are pretending but this is not working. It outputs the next error:

`inlineformset_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'
`

Comment: By the way, the output of initial is as follows

`[{'language': <Language: Spanish>, 'value': ''}, {'language': <Language: English>, 'value': ''}, {'language': <Language: Greek>, 'value': ''}]
`

Comment: Ok, I see. You don't have to bother about TranslationInline get_formset() but rather WordAdmin._create_formsets(): https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1766 I will edit my answer tomorrow. I'm on my mobile phone and going to sleep. :P

Comment: I'm trying with WordAdmin._create_formsets() but i'm still getting the same error, I don't understand why are you doing this 
`kwargs['initial'] = initial`. Have a good night :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Still not tested, hope this will work. :)

Comment: Another solution would be to create missing Translation objects in the database and provide default data, directly in TranslationInline.get_queryset(). The code would be cleaner, but I don't like the idea of creating entries inside get_queryset(), nor the idea that a GET requests may create entries in the database.

Comment: Still not working, it shows the language column, but it's not showing the language name. It shows just a '-'.

Comment: And did you try to fix it?

Comment: Sure, but I can't find what's wrong.

The initial contains:
`[{'id': None, 'value': '', 'language': <Language: Spanish>}, {'id': None, 'value': '', 'language': <Language: English>}, {'id': None, 'value': '', 'language': <Language: Greek>}]`

Comment: Maybe language should actually be the language id rather than the language object.

Comment: `[{'id': None, 'language': 'Spanish', 'value': ''}, {'id': None, 'language': 'English', 'value': ''}, {'id': None, 'language': 'Greek', 'value': ''}]`

still not working ^^'

Comment: The id, not the name.

Comment: I fixed it and it still not working. The good part is that im getting the same number of rows as languages I have. I think the problem is in the `<td class="field-language>` because it's showing me just '-'.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to fix. Does it show a default value if you set `{'value': "foobar"}` instead of `{'value': ""}` ?

Comment: I edited my answer, but since what you are asking for is quite unusual, it is hard for me to debug remotely.

Comment: With the new code the language problem of not showing the tags still persist. I don't know where should i try to fix it.

Comment: Maybe try with `{'language_id': l.pk}` instead of `{'language': l}`, or with `{'language': l.pk}`.

Comment: No, it's not working with that. As you can see [here](http://imgur.com/nF5Agoh), language is not inserting neither the id nor the name.  But I don't understand that, because when I had 3 languages, i was getting 3 rows, and I inserted another and now It's displaying 4 rows. I mean, the number of rows It's ok, the problem is that the form is not getting the right information about the language.

Comment: Try to get it work without `readonly_fields`. I would be easier to debug.

Comment: It gives me the same view without the language column. I can send the form to the application, but obviously it returns an Integrity error because I'm not sending it the language id.

Comment: I just tested, it should work when you don't have a readonly_fields. If the column does not appear, it is just that you didn't set 'language' in fields or something like this.

Comment: For some reason i added editable=False on `language = models.ForeignKey(Language, editable=False)` removing this made your code work. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set `editable=False` in the field properties, the field will be read-only in admin. For example:

`language = models.ForeignKey(Language, editable=False)`

Comment: I am getting textboxes without selects now, so I can't reference which language I want. I am gettint integrety error right now. I think i explained it better [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092706/how-can-i-use-all-objects-in-a-table-as-a-label-input-in-a-model-in-djangos-a/36094120#comment59832499_36093593)